# Understanding Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Trying to understand this bit of code using variadic templates:

```
template <typename... T>
struct FooGroup;

template <typename... FooTypes, typename... BarTypes>
struct TEST<FooGroup<FooTypes...>, BarGroup<BarTypes...>>
```

I know variadic templates allows you to pass in unknown type of unknown amount. However, this is confusing to me. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
template <typename... T>
struct FooGroup;
```

declare `FooGroup` as a `struct` that receive a variadic list of type template parameter.

```
template <typename... FooTypes, typename... BarTypes>
struct TEST<FooGroup<FooTypes...>, BarGroup<BarTypes...>>
```

is part of template specialization.

I suppose that `TEST` is declared as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct TEST;
```

so receiving two template types parameter.

With

```
template <typename... FooTypes, typename... BarTypes>
struct TEST<FooGroup<FooTypes...>, BarGroup<BarTypes...>>
```

you declare a partial specialization of `TEST` in case the first template parameter is in the form `FooGroup<FooTypes...>` (where `FooTypes...` is a variadic list of template parameters) and the second template parameter is in the form `BarGroup<BarTypes...>` (where I suppose `BarGroup` is defined almost as `FooGroup` and `BarTypes...` is another variadic list of template parameters)

Comment: So basically `FooGroup` is just a declaration to say it takes in a variadic list of template parameters which is `FooTypes` in this case. Are there times where this is necessary?

Comment: @alittlebirdy it is hard to answer that without seeing exactly how `FooGroup`, `BarGroup` , and `TEST` actually use their template parameters.